# curve of best fit in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to fit linear and nonlinear regression to my data (linear and logarithmic) in one graph. how can I do this with pgfplots?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: `pgfplots` can do linear regression _via_ `pgfplotstable` (this is covered in the manual). Beyond that, or if you need more control over linear fitting, you'll need to fit externally then use the results in LaTeX.

Comment: You can, in principle, accomplish this in `LuaLaTeX.'  But it'll be more trouble than it's worth, so @JosephWright's suggestion is likely preferable.